# Are elements of a $C^*$-Algebra strictly positive iff their spectrum is strictly positive?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ be a $C^*$-Algebra. An element $a\in A$ is said to be positive iff $a=a^*$ and the spectrum $\sigma(a)$ is nonnegative, ie. $\sigma(a)\subset[0,\infty)$. This is equivalent to $\varphi(a)\ge 0$ for all positive linear functionals $\varphi:A\to\mathbb{C}$.

The standard definition for $a$ being strictly positive seems to be that $\varphi(a)>0$ for all nonzero positive linear functionals. Is this definition equivalent to (the more intuitive characterization) $a=a^*$ and $\sigma(a)\subset(0,\infty)$?

I know that this is true in the unital case (proof: An equivalent definition of $a$ being strictly positive is that $a$ is positive and $\overline{aAa}=A$. Assume $a$ is strictly positive, then $a$ is invertible, because $\|axa-1\|<\frac{1}{2}$ for some $x\in A$, hence
$axa$ is invertible, which means that $a$ has a left and right inverse, thus
$a$ is invertible. So $a$ is invertible and positive, ie. $\sigma(a)\subset(0,\infty)$. Conversely assume that $\sigma(a)\subset(0,\infty)$ and $a=a^*$, then $a$ is positive and invertible. Because $a$ is invertible we have $aAa=A$, so $a$ is strictly positive.)

What can be said about the non-unital case?

Comment: I guess $a\in A$ is positive iff $a$ is Hermitian and $\sigma(a)$ is subset of $[0, \infty) $.

Comment: Does hermitian mean self-adjoint, ie. $a=a^*$? Then this is already implied by $\sigma(a)\subset\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Yes. By Hermitian I mean Self adjoint. Remember $\sigma (a) \subset \mathbb{R}$ doesn't imply $a$ is self adjoint. For example Take take the nilpotent operator $T$ on $\mathbb{C} ^2$  defined by $T(e_1)= 0, T(e_2)= e_1$. Here  $ \sigma(T)  =\{0\} \subset \mathbb{R}$ but T is not self adjoint.

Comment: You're right, of course! I edited the question accordingly, thanks :)

Comment: For your question this may be a good hint. If $f$ is a positive linear functional on a $C^*$ algebra $A$ with norm 1 and if $a$ is a self-adjoint element then show that $f(a)$ lies in closed convex hull of the $\sigma (a)$.

Comment: That's a nice fact, that would give me $\sigma(a)\subset(0,\infty) \Rightarrow f(a)>0$ for self adjoint $a$. I have to think about it later, but thanks for now :)

Comment: @timon: I found a proof for $\text{conv}(\sigma(a)) = \{\phi(a) \,:\,\text{$\phi$ is a state of $A$}\}$ in John B. Conway's 'A course in operator theory' (Prop 7.8). Even in the book it sounds as if it were true in general, but it's only true in the unital case! (every strictly positive element $a$ is a counter example)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $ A $ is non-unital, then the spectrum of an element of $ A $ is defined via the unitization $ A^{+} $ of $ A $. Hence, $ \lambda \in \sigma(a) $ if and only if $ (a,- \lambda) \in A^{+} $ is not invertible. It follows readily that $ 0 \in \sigma(a) $ for any $ a \in A $. If $ 0 \notin \sigma(a) $, then $ (a,0_{\Bbb{C}}) $ would be invertible in $ A^{+} $, but multiplying $ (a,0_{\Bbb{C}}) $ by any $ (b,z) \in A^{+} $ can never give us $ (0_{A},1_{\Bbb{C}}) $, so we get a contradiction.

Therefore, self-adjoint elements of $ A $ can never have strictly positive spectra if $ A $ is non-unital.

Comment: Of course you're right, how could I miss something so obvious. That explains why an alternative characterization for strictly positive elements other than $\sigma(a)\subset(0,\infty)$ is needed in the non-unital case. So the answer to my question is no, and with timons comment i may find an easier proof for the unital case. I may add the easier proof later, when i find it. Thanks everyone :)

Comment: @Kalua: No problem! I hope that you find what you need! :)

Answer (score 5):

As you note, the notion of strictly positive is irrelevant on unital C$^*$-algebras. But it is a different notion in the non-unital case. Consider the algebra of compact operators $K(H)$ on a separable Hilbert space. It has a strictly positive element, because every separable C$^*$-algebra has one; but no compact operator is invertible.

Explicitly, in terms of matrix units you can consider $x=\sum_n\frac1n\,e_{nn}$. This is strictly positive because it is easy to check that $x K(H) x$ contains all rank-one operators.